# C# - Serializar fechas sin tiempo

Tags: datetime

Tengo una pregunta general. Una servicio de mi servidor tiene que enviar fechas sin tiempo. Por ejemplo, fechas de cumpleaños. La pregunta que me surge es: si no hay tiempo, tan solo debo serializar la fecha como string. En c# así:

`date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Al principio estaba enviando la fecha de nacimiento serializada en Unix Milliseconds y tenía problemas al interpretar la fecha (el cliente me interpretaba una fecha `20-04-1932 00:00:00` como `19-04-1932 23:00:00 GMT+01`).

Pero para que serializarla si no quiero el tiempo? Mi fecha de nacimiento es igual en todas las partes del mundo.

Es correcto o estoy ignorando alguna cosa?

Comment: Probaste añadiendo **.Date** a tu fecha? -> `tufecha.Date` bastaría =)

Comment: Si , si hago .Date significa que tiene hora 0, minuto 0 y segondo 0. Cuando lo serializo pasando la fecha a UTC y en Unix Timestamp, me resta las horas y minutos y me voy al día anterior. Luego el cliente no podía representar la fecha que le estaba enviando.